# Visual C++ MFC Application- Event not receiving in child dialog

Tags: mfc, event-handling, dialog, mouseevent

I have created a derived control handling events as mouse movement, left button down up,down etc.
And I have a popup dialog and within that dialog, three child dialogs.
When I use the derived control in my popup dialog, it is working properly.
But when I place my control in any of the child dialog, the mouse events are not handled.
Please suggest a solution.

Thanks in advance,
Madhan

Answer (score 0):

Must to pass forward the events. Catch them on the child dialog with the respective message handlers and then forward them using the ::SendMessage method.
The popup dialog possibly catched up automatically the mouse events and enabled to be forwarded towards.